# ASSERTION FAILED ERROR

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to find the optical flow between two sequence of images,when I run the program it shows up assertion failed at calcOpticalFlowFarneback() function.Can anyone help me with this issue.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<opencv\cv.h>
#include<opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2\calib3d\calib3d.hpp>
#include<opencv2\core\core.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
void drawOptFlowMap (const Mat& flow, Mat& cflowmap, int step, double scale, const    
Scalar& color) 
{
  for(int y = 0; y < cflowmap.rows; y += step)
    for(int x = 0; x < cflowmap.cols; x += step)
    {
        const Point2f& fxy = flow.at<Point2f>(y, x);
        line(cflowmap, Point(x,y), Point(cvRound(x+fxy.x), cvRound(y+fxy.y)),
             color);
        circle(cflowmap, Point(cvRound(x+fxy.x), cvRound(y+fxy.y)), 1, color, -1);
    }
} 
int main()
{
  Mat flow,cflow;
  Mat Previous_Gray=imread("image2.png");

  Mat Current_Gray=imread("image3.png");
  cvtColor(Current_Gray,Current_Gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);
  cvNamedWindow("optical Flow", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
  calcOpticalFlowFarneback(Previous_Gray,Current_Gray,flow,0.5, 3, 15, 3, 5, 1.2, 0);
  cvtColor(Previous_Gray, cflow, CV_GRAY2BGR);
  drawOptFlowMap(flow, cflow, 32, 50, CV_RGB(0, 255, 0));
  imshow("optical Flow", cflow);


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you include the assertion output?

Comment: Have you checked that your input data has the correct format?

Comment: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (prev0.size() == next0.size() && prev0.channels() == next0.channels() == 1 && pyr_scale<1> in unknown function,file ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\video\src\optflowgf.cpp, line 579

Comment: Your question title is not overly descriptive, try to choose something a bit more descriptive/specific.  Also, try going through your code first to try and identify which sections work and which don't (one way to do this is to comment out parts).  Once you have identified exactly the line/section causing your problem, edit your question with the minimum amount of code required to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @ilent2: Although the question title and the question itself is not specific and it is pretty easy to track out the problem, I would not say that author must add some details. All necessary are given, it is possible to specify some issues in the code that possibly make a problem.

Comment: @marol I agree, all necessary are given.  My suggestion was mainly about readability/conciseness, otherwise the question seemed fine.

Answer (score 2):

`Mat imread(const string& filename, int flags=1)`, what is the call you're using in the line `Mat Previous_Gray=imread("image2.png");` returns an 3 channel rgb image. So beacuse part of the assertion

> prev0.channels() == next0.channels() == 1

is false. Did you forget to convert PreviousGray *before* call calcOpticalFlowFarneback?

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imread

Comment: I have made the changes as per your suggestion,the program runs without any errors but opens a window without any output..